# Action Scheduler not running

Tags: actions, wp-cron

I am trying to learn how to use the action scheduler so I am hoping somehow can give me some good pointers. I've got this code:

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'wootomation_schedule' ) );
add_action( 'wootomation_import', array( $this, 'wootomation_do_action' ) );

function wootomation_schedule() {
    // if ( false === as_next_scheduled_action( 'wootomation_import' ) ) {
    //  as_schedule_recurring_action( time(), 30, 'wootomation_import' );
    // }
    if ( false === as_next_scheduled_action( 'wootomation_import' ) ) {
        as_enqueue_async_action( 'wootomation_import' );
    }
}

function wootomation_do_action() {
    var_dump('test');
    wp_mail( 'hello@wpharvest.com', 'test AS', 'Action schedule completed' );
}
```

Which appears to create the action but it never runs. I tried refreshing the front end of the website but didn't help.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to get it to run?

And the 2nd question would be, is this the right approach for breaking up some heavy indexing, maybe with args such as page: "0-100", page: "101-200", etc.

Thanks,
Dragos

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/libraries/action-scheduler/action-scheduler.php' );

/**
 * Schedule an action with the hook 'eg_midnight_log' to run at midnight each day
 * so that our callback is run then.
 */
function eg_log_action_data() {
    if ( false === as_next_scheduled_action( 'eg_midnight_log' ) ) {
        as_schedule_recurring_action( strtotime( 'midnight tonight' ), DAY_IN_SECONDS, 'eg_midnight_log' );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'eg_log_action_data' );

/**
 * A callback to run when the 'eg_midnight_log' scheduled action is run.
 */
function eg_log_action_data() {
    error_log( 'It is just after midnight on ' . date( 'Y-m-d' ) );
}
add_action( 'eg_midnight_log', 'eg_log_action_data' );
```

Docs Link: https://actionscheduler.org/usage/#scheduling-an-action

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just got back into the project. This seems to kinda work but once I add that code for a more heavy indexing, it freezes the page until the whole thing finishes. Is this normal? I would have thought this is asynchronous.